# Same Sample Size, Python ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples

Tags: python, linear-regression, valueerror

I checked that these objects all had the same shape and am still getting this error, with a list or single item in the x spot:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Still can't get it to run with the variable names, but I was able to when I used double brackets around the column names:

```
model = lr.fit(df[["Total_Batting_Salary","Total_Pitching_Salary"]],df["Wins"])
```